# Trouble updating BooleanField with Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django

Using Django 1.11 and Python 3.4

I have a model:

```
class ToDo(models.Model):
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want users to be able to update this field for the model by clicking a checkbox, so I made a ModelForm as follows:

```
class CompletedForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ToDo
    fields = ['completed']
```

The problem I am having is understanding how I can get the database to update whenever the user clicks the checkbox, so that the completed field will toggle between True or False.  In views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    for x in range(0, all_todos.count()):
        a = all_todos[x]
        completedform = CompletedForm(request.POST, instance=a)        


else:
    for x in range(0, all_todos.count()):
        a = all_todos[x]
        print(a)
        completedform = CompletedForm(instance=a)
```

I've rendered the checkboxes in the event of either GET or POST method, and linked each box to a particular instance.  I assume that most of the logic will take place in the POST method since this is making a change to the database.

Thank you

Comment: `all_todos` is a queryset with all all ToDo instanse from `POST` request?

Comment: Ah yes.  Sorry for leaving that out.

Answer (score 0):

If in `POST` data you have a list of `ToDo` ids, then exist a more easy way to update all data.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ids = request.POST.get('todo') # we should get all id from ToDo, should be int
    ToDo.objects.filter(pk__in=ids).update(completed=True)
```

Comment: Will give this a try, but how do you suggest I access the POST branch of my if else statement?  The page initial renders as a GET request and clicking the checkbox doesn't then change it to a POST request

Comment: @KWalsh you should use html for for this